# expected identifier before the name of the function on first line

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, expected-exception

I have a code:

```
void switch (int *a, int *b) 
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

It's the function I include in other .c file by this one .h file:

```
#ifndef SWITCHINT_H
#define SWITCHINT_H

void switch (int *a, int *b);

#endif
```

But console prints that:

```
switchInt.c:1:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘switch’
 void switch (int *a, int *b);s
switchInt.h:4:6: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘switch’
 void switch (int *a, int *b);
```

What should i do?

Comment: `switch` is a [reserved word](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-keywords-reserved-words/).

Comment: Also, is there really an `s` character after `void switch (int *a, int *b);`?

Comment: first code form switchInt.c; The second one from switchInt.h

Comment: Try changing name of function from `switch` to `swap`.

Comment: No, there isn't any 's' at the end, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred due to a [reserved](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-keywords-reserved-words/) name of the function ("switch")

Thanks [Fiddling Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2993960/fiddling-bits) for help!

P.S: I'm sorry for being so blind :(